# Can I use try catch (Exception Handling) in Netlogo

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, netlogo

how can I use exception handling in NetLogo? If I have an error it displays run-time error. I do not want to display this error, instead I want to catch it at run-time and do something else instead (like in c# or vb.net). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`carefully`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#carefully) primitive does exactly that, and the error message is available using [`error-message`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#error-message):

```
carefully [
  print mean [] ; try to take the mean of an empty list
] [
  print error-message ; or do something else instead...
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Really appreciate your guidance :)